# JSPG0122E: Unable to parse EL function in Websphere 7

Tags: java, jstl, el, websphere-7

I am moving a web application to Websphere 7 and I am running into an error with my JSP page.

```
JSPG0227E: Exception caught while translating /WEB-INF/jsp/snet/destinationTripReport.jsp:  
/WEB-INF/jsp/snet/destinationTripReport.jsp(211,8) --> JSPG0122E: Unable to parse EL function ${destForm.flightTable.get(loop.index).tripId}.
```

The portion of the JSP where the error is coming from looks like this.

```
<c:forEach items="${destForm.flightTable}" var="entry" varStatus="loop">
    <!-- content -->
    <tr class="table-info">
        <td>${destForm.flightTable.get(loop.index).tripId}</td>
        <td>${destForm.flightTable.get(loop.index).actualArrival}</td>
        <td>${destForm.flightTable.get(loop.index).comment}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

What is confusing to me the most is that this runs using TOMCAT, but the error occurs while using Websphere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Problem

Websphere 7 uses JSP 2.1 (Java EE5). JSP 2.1 does NOT support method calls within EL expressions so `${destForm.flightTable.get(loop.index)}`
is invalid because of the call to get() within the EL expression.

### Solution:

To solve your problem, your EL expression should be `${destForm.flightTable[loop.index].tripId}` assuming that `destForm.flightTable` is a List/Array which can be accessed by index.

*Note: JSP 2.2+ (Java EE6+) allows method calls in EL expression like you did.*